# Regarding Trigger email

Tags: triggers, bulk

I have a trigger code:

```
Trigger AutoEmailsending on Order (after update) 
{
    Map<Id,Order> Orderdetail = new Map<Id,Order>();
    Set<Id> Accountid = new Set<Id>();
    for(order or1 : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(or1.Status == 'Submitted' && (or1.Subtype__c =='Offer' || or1.Subtype__c =='ASP'))
        {
            Orderdetail.put(or1.id,or1);
            Accountid.add (or1.accountid);
        }
    }
    List<Attachment> Attachmentlst = [Select Id,
                                             ParentId, 
                                             Name,
                                             BodyLength,
                                             Body,
                                             Description 
                                        From Attachment 
                                        where ParentId=:Orderdetail.keyset()];

    Map<String, Blob> resources = new Map<String, Blob>();
    for(StaticResource resource:[SELECT Name, Body FROM StaticResource where Name IN ('TC_for_France','TC_for_Italy')]) 
    {
        resources.put(resource.Name, resource.Body);
    }
    User currentUser = [Select Id,Phone,name from User where Id =:System.UserInfo.getUserId()];

    for (attachment attachmentlst1 : attachmentlst )
    {
        List<String> Toaddress = new List<String>();
        List<String> CCaddress = new List<String>(); 
        String Orderid = attachmentlst1.ParentId;
        String ResourceName;
        String TCname;
        string  strHtmlBody;

        String Emailaddress = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
        String CustomerServiceEmail =         Order_Configuration__c.getInstance().Customer_Service_Email__c;
        string SellingOfficePhone =         Order_Configuration__c.getInstance().Selling_Office_Phone__c;
        String OrderNumber = Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).OrderNumber;

        List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List <Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
        if(Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Email_Address__c != null)
        {
            Toaddress.add(Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Email_Address__c);
        }
        String Market = Accountmap.get(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).accountid).Market__c;
        CCaddress.add(emailaddress);
        if(CustomerServiceEmail !=null)
        CCaddress.add(CustomerServiceEmail);

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(Toaddress);
        mail.setCcAddresses(CCaddress);
        if(Orderdetail.get(attachmentlst1.ParentId).Subtype__c =='Offer' || Market=='FR')
        {
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Trade Order-FR'); 
            ResourceName = 'TC_for_France';
            TCname = 'CONDITIONS_GENERALES_DEVENTE.pdf';

        }

}
```

The trigger should send mail for the created user of the particular order,it should not send mail for last modified user of Particular order How to over come this Scenario,Dont need about the logic what i have to add  lines in the trigger code